# More reads in cloud firestore with useeffect react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I have 30 000 reads in few minutes in my cloud firestore for 4 documents
I don't understand, i stay in the same screen,i don't touch anything and i don't reload my component.

Here is my code :

```
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = db.collection('chats').onSnapshot((snapshot)=> (
            setChats(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })))
        ));

        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, []);
```

I tried to don't return unsubscribe() ant nothing.
Have you got an idea ?

Comment: Is your component rendering many times due to a parent component's behavior?

Comment: It's my HomeScreen , before I look just if i always connected.

Comment: Make sure that it's not rendering a large number of times for some reason. You can do this by adding a console.log in a useEffect

Comment: I used console.log in my useeffect and i call only one times